# Incompatible error while using Quartz with apache camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, quartz

I am getting below exception with these dependencies. Since there is no 3.8.0 version for quartz how can I manage this? Is the only way is to downgrade the core camel version to 3.0.0-M4?

```
Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.springboot.QuartzComponentAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
```

Pom dependency as follows

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quartz2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quartz2-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
    <!-- <version>${camel.springboot.version}</version> -->
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jpa-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

From camel-3.0, you should use camel-quartz instead of camel-quartz2.

https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3-migration-guide.html#_renamed_components